# Visual Studio 2015 - Other instances of the selected variable in the scrollbar are gone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, scrollbar

I recently upgraded from VS2013 to 2015. And I've noticed something missing from my ScrollBar, and I can't find anywhere on how to enable/disable it in 2015, nor anything about it being removed from 2015.

I am talking about when I click/mark some code, a Property for instance, I see blue markers on the ScrollBar where this is being used. That's gone for me in 2015.

Here is an image of the 2013 version [Photo of Scrollbar with Blue dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bfv4.jpg)

So my question, can I enable this in 2015? I find it really frustrating to not have it, since I used it a lot.

Hope I've explained it good enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. It was the extension called Productivity Power Tools that did this for me.